# fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'http'

Tags: bitbucket, solaris, git-clone

I had tried to clone my repository on Solaris using git bash but I got the below error

Cloning into 'devops'...
warning: templates not found /usr/local/share/git-core/templates
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'http'

Answer (score 1):

I have always seen that error message when Git was compiled without curl-devel installed.

For Solaris, that would be [`CSWlibcurl-dev/`](https://www.opencsw.org/packages/CSWlibcurl-dev/).
Once installed, recompile Git and you are good to go.